# AWS api gateway for javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

So im experienced in implementing AWS api gateway sdk in android, but having trouble implementing in for a website. If i follow the aws api gateway tutorial [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-javascript.html). Doesn't that expose my aws access key and more private information for anyone to see (view page source)?

Basically all i want is a user to click a button, and then we send their username they entered to our dyanmoDB via our api methods we made in API gateway.

Can anyone provide step by step directions, for a simple button click and send string to dynamoDB use case?

(Im experienced in android, but not at all in javascript)

Hope for your wisdom!

Comment: Take a look at the [docs here on integrating Cognito User Pools with API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html). Here are some [docs on providing AWS access to externally authenticated users](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_federated-users.html).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to this part:

```
var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
   accessKey: 'ACCESS_KEY',
   secretKey: 'SECRET_KEY',
});
```

Those are the *user's credentials* not yours. That example is assuming you're using AWS for authentication, meaning that you have an IAM user/role set up for your users. The keys for that/those IAM roles are what are used to communicate with API Gateway. Presumably, this would be entered by the user in some HTML form input boxes and not hard-coded in your code.

If you don't want to directly use IAM for authentication, you could use OAuth or Amazon Cognito.